# Auto Authenticate user on Azure Platform

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, autologin

I have a situation wherein, we're listing third party content on our website, now what they want only authentic user from our userbase would be able to consume it's content, however for that, the only way they have is to authentic via Azure, they do not want to take the authorization token from us, they want we auto login user on Azure and then when they communicate with Azure, they will get the Authorization token and then they will authenticate the user and allow them to consume their content.

So we're planning to have the users information (Username and password) on Azure SQL, and once the user logs in on our website, we will auto authenticate them on Azure using the same user information on Azure SQL, once authenticated, Azure will generate the authentication token which this Third party company will use and authenticate our users.

So just want to know is the above scenario possible, or how can we achieve the same?

Comment: This sounds really odd to me. You should not be storing passwords for users in your database. You say they don't take authentication token from you but then also that they would use the Azure-generated token to authenticate the user. So are they able to accept an access token from you?

Comment: No, as per their setup, they need Azure token to authorize the user to access their content, they don't care whether the is authenticated or not, we've anonymized the username (email) so the Azure SQL will not have actual user info which is in my system, for e.g. abbas.electricwala@abc.com in my system will become user12329@abc.com (12329) will be the user id in my system.